# React - Can't setState using input field attribute as key

Tags: reactjs, react-redux, react-hooks

> Issue:

I am unable to change the state duynamically. I need to change the state object's key as per the input field's "name" attribute.

> Code:

```
const addressValue = (e) => {
        setAddress(state => ({
            ...state,
            [e.target.name]: e.target.value
        }));
    };
/****************************************************************
* giving error while typing "Cannot read property 'name' of null"
*****************************************************************/
<form onSubmit={submitHandler}>
        <div className="form-group">
            <input id="address-line-1" className="form-control" value={address.line1}
                onChange={addressValue} name="line1" type="text" placeholder="Line 1" />
        </div>
        <div className="form-group">
            <input id="address-line-2" className="form-control" value={address.line2}
                onChange={addressValue} name="line2" type="text" placeholder="Line 2" />
        </div>
</form>
```

> Object's initial value

```
{
line1 : "CA",
line2 : "US"
}
```

Comment: Read [here](https://reactjs.org/docs/events.html) about reacts synthetic events. Basically, because you're using a functional update, the `event` has been reset before it gets used. Solution would be to use `e.persist()` or save the relevant values to other variables outside the event object. Or another option would be to not use a functional update, since your new state is not derived from the previous state.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Reactjs - TypeError: Cannot read property 'value' of null](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61870886/reactjs-typeerror-cannot-read-property-value-of-null)

Comment: Thank you so much! It worked and I learned something new.
I really respect people like you who take time to help others.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to Brian Thompson.
Since I was using a functional update, the event was resetting before it was getting used.
So, I used **e.persist()**.

```
const addressValue = (e) => {
    e.persist();
    setAddress(state => ({
        ...state,
        [e.target.name]: e.target.value
    }));
};
```

Comment: `const addressValue = ({target;{name,value}}) => {` would be easier, Brian also said: `or save the relevant values to other variables outside the event object. `

Answer (score 0):

As an alternative what you can do is create a custom `useForm` hook like so:

```
import { useState } from 'react';

export const useForm = initialValues => {
    const [values, setValues] = useState(initialValues);

    return {
        values,
        handleChange: e => {
            setValues({
                ...values,
                [e.target.name]: e.target.value,
            });
        },
        reset: () => setValues(initialValues),
    };
};
```

Then you can import and use it in any form component: (for example here's a sign in form)

```
import React from 'react';
import { useForm } from '../hooks/useForm';
import history from '../history';

export default function SignInForm() {
    const { values, handleChange, reset } = useForm({ email: '', password: '' });

    const handleSubmit = e => {
        e.preventDefault();
        // POST request or however you handle the submission
        reset();
        history.goBack();
    };

    return (
        <form onSubmit={handleSubmit} className='SignIn__form'>
            <input
                className='SignIn__form--input'
                type='email'
                name='email'
                placeholder='Enter your email...'
                onChange={handleChange}
                value={values.email}
            />
            <input
                className='SignIn__form--input'
                type='password'
                name='password'
                placeholder='Enter your password...'
                onChange={handleChange}
                value={values.password}
            />
            <button className='Button' type='submit'>
                Sign In
            </button>
        </form>
    );
}
```